# Spring @RequestBody Json to LinkedHashMap

Tags: json, spring, rest

I do receive the following json data into one of my RESTful spring web service. I do retrieve data from body of the request using spring @RequestBody. the data is retrieved as LinkedHashMap with two java.util.ArrayList(s) each for Player and Fixture objects. But the problem is that each object in java.util.ArrayList(s), is not of Player or Fixture type; its again of LinkedHashMap type. Is it possible to tell the spring to transform data into java.util.ArrayList(s). One list should contain objects of Player and other should contain objects of Fixture type.

```
{"Player":[
    {"idPlayer":101,"FirstName":"Stevenson","LastName":"Martin"},
    {"idPlayer":102,"FirstName":"Kevin","LastName":"Main"}
  ],
"Fixture":[
     {"idFixture":1,"HomeTeamId":"2","AwayTeamId":"9"},
     {"idFixture":2,"HomeTeamId":"6","AwayTeamId":"2"},
     {"idFixture":3,"HomeTeamId":"5","AwayTeamId":"3"}
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible if the top element is a Map.

But if you can change the Map to another class it is possible

```
public class Form {
    private List<Player> player;
    private List<Fixture> Fixture;
    //gettters and setters
}
```